# Generalization error for simple linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, probability, distribution

Lets say we have a training data and we have estimated a fit for a model of square ft of living area vs price of houses. Suppose we know the probability distribution of sq ft and for a fixed sq ft we know the probability distribution of its price. Now, we know the joint probability for each sq ft and price pair. How do I calculate the generalization error(both total and for a particular sq ft)??

Comment: No, MSE is just the mean loss. We need a loss function which in this case in squared function. But generalization error is something else. Its defined as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_error)